# Get how much line contains in side polygon

Tags: area, polygons

I have area of the polygon and lenght of the line some thing like this in picture.
[image]

How can i get that how much (%) line is inside/contains/overlap with polygon like in picture is almost 60%. what will be the formula?

Comment: You need to determine *which* of the sides intersects your line and *where* it intersects. In more complicated situations, it may also happen that the line enters and leaves the polygon (maybe even several times)

Comment: yes a line can be in complex format. so what to do

Comment: it is easy to compare area vs area but in my case here is area vs length. any luck?